# jar file doesn't run

Tags: java, jar, alert

I'm fairly new to Java and having recently installed the latest JDK I'm having trouble getting files with a .jar extension to run. When I double-click them I simply get an alert noise and nothing more. I have tried jarfix.exe, tried changing the associated program in folder options and even reinstalling Java. Not sure what else to do. Any help greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: as an addendum I should mention that when I right-click a jar file I'm given the option "extract" rather than "add to archive"...

Comment: that means it's probably not an executable jar.

Comment: If you still cannot run that after trying, please post the noise, that could be helpful.

Comment: @Matt, that is because jars are just zip-files with cream on top.

Answer (score 2):

Try running from the command line and see what error messages you get.

```
java -jar your.jar
```

Comment: I get the following:                                                        C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\lingpipe-4.1.0>jar -jar lingpipe-4.1.0.jar
Illegal option: j
Usage: jar {ctxui}[vfm0Me] [jar-file] [manifest-file] [entry-point] [-C dir] fil
es ...
Options:
    -c  create new archive
    -t  list table of contents for archive
    -x  extract named (or all) files from archive
    -u  update existing archive
    -v  generate verbose output on standard output
    -f  specify archive file name
    -m  include manifest information from specified manifest file

Comment: -e  specify application entry point for stand-alone application
        bundled into an executable jar file
    -0  store only; use no ZIP compression
    -M  do not create a manifest file for the entries
    -i  generate index information for the specified jar files
    -C  change to the specified directory and include the following file

Comment: You typed jar where you should have typed java

Answer (score 2):

Within your jar/zip file go to the INF\MANIFEST.MF file, there should be a line that looks like

```
Main-Class: ClassName
```

if there is not one, try adding it.

Comment: If application requeries additional lib it can be set in MANIFEST.MF as:

    Class-Path: a.jar b.jar c.jar ...

Answer (score 0):

A java jar file is a library file containing compiled java files (with a `.class` file) and a `META-INF\MANIFEST.MF` file, which contains information about the jar file. Think of what a `.jar` file is to java, as a `.dll` is to Windows.

To run your jar file, you need to install java and, on command-line, type:

```
java -cp myJar.jar classname
```

where `classname` is a fully qualified java class name (e.g. `com.neurologic.main.MyProgram`).

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifest_file) (or [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/JAR/basics/manifest.html#applications)) is more information on how to bundle your application (that contains `public static void main(String[] args)` method) into your JAR file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Not every jar file is executable. You can test it easily, in a shell type `java -jar /<path-to-jar>/<jar-file-name>.jar`, if nothing happens (but an error), the java lib is not an application.
2. If the actual OS is a *nix System, verify that the current file attributed allow execution for you.
3. The `jar` extension may be associated with a different local application, like an archiving tool. Solving this again is OS dependent.

---

Here are some steps to test/perform, then it should work:

1. open cmd and execute `java -version` - you *should* get a response from the java executable. If *not*, add the JREs bin folder to your PATH environment.
2. navigate to the folder that has your jar file (like: `C:\jars`)
3. *Now* execute the command `java -jar lingpipe-4.1.0.jar`

Personally I *doubt* that the lingpipe library is an *executable* java archive (but can't test/prove it from my current place). [Here is a page that includes a link to command shell examples](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/web/install.html). I suggest you just look at those pages and follow their instructions.

Comment: thanks for the overwhelmingly rapid responses :)Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

C:\Documents and Settings\Matt>java -jar your_jar.jar
Unable to access jarfile your_jar.jar

C:\Documents and Settings\Matt>jar -jar lingpipe-4.1.0.jar
Unable to access jarfile lingpipe-4.1.0.jar

C:\Documents and Settings\Matt>cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\lingpipe-4.1
.0

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\lingpipe-4.1.0>jar -jar lingpipe-4.1.0.jar
Illegal option: j
Usage: jar {ctxui}[vfm0Me] [jar-file] [manifest-file] [entry-point] [-C dir] fil
es ...
Option

Comment: christ sorry for my formatting, i'm need to get used to the tools on this message board

Answer (score 0):

Create a **.mf** file, inside it put your main class:

```
Main-Class: className
```

Do not forget to add a new blank line!

Then save file and do:

```
jar -cmfv ***mfFile***.mf ***selectAName***.jar ***mainClass***.class
```